# libcore.io.ErrnoException: null failed: errno 0 (Success)

Tags: android, fragment

I use this method in a Fragment and get this error,but in an activity it works good, How can I fix this?

```
File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "AA");        
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {     
        if (`!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {//I get the exception here`    
            return null;  
        }   
    }   
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());   
    File mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");   
    return Uri.fromFile(mediaFile);
```